# Our iOS app package size is more than doubled in AppStore compared to what we submitted

Tags: ios

Our .ipa file submitted to Apple is only around 40MB but the apps size shown in the store is over 90MB. By downloading our ipa file from iTunes, we found that the reason. It is because our executable binary which is (92MB without compression) is encrypted by Apple and not very compressible anymore. It can be compressed to 85MB. But it could be compressed to about 35MB before submitting to apple.

Obviously, we are not alone as I can see some other discussions around this issue long time ago.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/why-is-our-app-twice-as-large-as-what-we-submitted-contagious-zeros/

However, we found that actually Facebook app and Facebook Messenger somehow are probably not encrypted by Apple. See the strings we dump from their binaries. Clearly lots of their strings, methodname, classname, etc are not encrypted. So their binary can be compressed to ~60%. On the other hand, in our app from appstore, we can hardly find any readable C string literals, methodname, classname, etc.

My question is if there is a way to (fully or partially) disable Apple's encryption on the binary, so that we can keep our original package size?

Some strings in FB messenger executable downloaded from iTunes:

```
@"FBVSPDeltaNewTransfer"
@"FBVSPDeltaTransferStatus"
@"FBVSPDeltaPaymentMethodUpdated"
@"FBVSPDeltaPaymentMethodRemoved"
@"FBVSPDeltaPaymentMethodPrimary"
@"FBVSPDeltaPinCode"
@"FBVSPDeltaPaymentNoOp"
@"FBVSPDeltaPaymentForcedFetch"
@"FBVSPDeltaPaymentEnable"
@56@0:8@16q24q32@40@48
@"<MNSyncProtocolPluginService>"
@"FBPaymentsPeerToPeerSPSnapshotController"
@"FBPaymentsPeerToPeerSPSequenceIdProvider"
@"FBPaymentsPeerToPeerSPSyncTokenProvider"
@"FBPaymentsPeerToPeerSPErrorCodeProvider"
@"FBPaymentsPeerToPeerSPDeltaHandlerMap"
@"FBPaymentsPeerToPeerSPPayloadHandler"
@"NSString"24@0:8@16
```

Comment: 1. Have you downloaded the app from the app store and compared it to the ipa you submitted? 2. Have you looked a where the size of your app is, that is what resources make up the majority of the size? 3. Images are essentially incompressible for png and jpg, they are compressed by the encoding. 4.It is not possible to compress an encrypted file, compression depends on redundancy that can be optimized, an encrypted file is essentially random bytes meaning there is no redundancy and thus un-compressible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, zaph.
1. Yes, I have downloaded the ipa file directly from iTunes and compare with the ipa file we submitted

2. Our asset files (images/etc) are 10% of the total size. And 90% size comes from the executable binary file. The reason the ipa file size is twice as big as original ipa file is mostly because the executable file is not compressible anymore after encryption

3.What we found that is Facebook main app and its messenger app seems not encrypted by apple by checking their binary. So our question is if it is possible to fully or partially stop encrypting our app